# Shortest way to get first item of `OrderedDict` in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, iterable

What's the shortest way to get first item of `OrderedDict` in Python 3?

My best:

```
list(ordered_dict.items())[0]
```

Quite long and ugly.

I can think of:

```
next(iter(ordered_dict.items()))       # Fixed, thanks Ashwini
```

But it's not very self-describing.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: using list is a bad idea. the entire list will be populate before you'll get the first item. Using next() is optimal because .items() return an iterator and will yield only one value.

Comment: What do you mean by shortest way? lesser number of characters?

Comment: I think you'll need an `iter` call too: `next(iter(d.items()))` as `.items` returns a View object.

Comment: @thefourtheye yes, less characters, but hopefully idiomatic too.

Comment: I was wondering if `next(iter(ordered_dict.items()))` this will advance the iterator or not. As expected it does not advance the iterator! Also is it safe to assume that `next(iter(ordered_dict.items()))` runs in `O(1)` time?

Comment: `next(iter(self.items()))` will give you the first pair `(key, val)`

Answer (score 76):

## Programming Practices for Readabililty

In general, if you feel like code is not self-describing, the usual solution is to factor it out into a well-named function:

```
def first(s):
    '''Return the first element from an ordered collection
       or an arbitrary element from an unordered collection.
       Raise StopIteration if the collection is empty.
    '''
    return next(iter(s))
```

With that [helper function](http://wiki.c2.com/?HelperFunction), the subsequent code becomes very readable:

```
>>> extension = {'xml', 'html', 'css', 'php', 'xhmtl'}
>>> one_extension = first(extension)
```

## Patterns for Extracting a Single Value from Collection

The usual ways to get an element from a *set*, *dict*, *OrderedDict*, generator, or other non-indexable collection are:

```
for value in some_collection:
    break
```

and:

```
value = next(iter(some_collection))
```

The latter is nice because the *next()* function lets you specify a default value if collection is empty or you can choose to let it raise an exception.  The *next()* function is also explicit that it is asking for the next item.

## Alternative Approach

If you actually need indexing and slicing and other sequence behaviors (such as indexing multiple elements), it is a simple matter to convert to a list with `list(some_collection)` or to use `[itertools.islice()][2]`:

```
s = list(some_collection)
print(s[0], s[1])

s = list(islice(n, some_collection))
print(s)
```

Comment: I like the latter option, but in your opinion is it better than ```list(ordered_dict.items())[0]```? If anything I think the ```[0]``` is more obvious.

Comment: @bedeabc `list(ordered_dict.items())[0]` goes ahead to create a _list of all items in the dict_, then takes the first item of that list, then throws away that list. You certainly don't want to do that.

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I understand, and have become comfortable with the next(iter()) pattern, but for trivially small data structures I don't see the issue with prioritising readability.

Comment: `next(iter(self.items()))` will give you the first pair `(key, val)`

Answer (score 32):

Use `popitem(last=False)`, but keep in mind that it removes the entry from the dictionary, i.e. is destructive.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
o = OrderedDict()
o['first'] = 123
o['second'] = 234
o['third'] = 345

first_item = o.popitem(last=False)
>>> ('first', 123)
```

For more details, have a look at the manual on [collections](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem). It also works with Python 2.x.

Comment: This is the best way for me, in case you don' t bother to destroy the dictionary

Comment: I want a non-destructive approach. How do I do it?

Comment: something besides: `next(iter(self.items()))` which gives `(key, val)`

Answer (score 5):

Subclassing and adding a method to `OrderedDict` would be the answer to clarity issues:

```python
>>> o = ExtOrderedDict(('a',1), ('b', 2))
>>> o.first_item()
('a', 1)
```

The implementation of `ExtOrderedDict`:

```
class ExtOrderedDict(OrderedDict):
    def first_item(self):
        return next(iter(self.items()))
```

Comment: is there not something without creating an iteratior? like an api from OD?

Answer (score 5):

Code that's readable, leaves the OrderedDict unchanged and doesn't needlessly generate a potentially large list just to get the first item:

```
for item in ordered_dict.items():
    return item
```

If ordered_dict is empty, None would be returned implicitly.

An alternate version for use inside a stretch of code:

```
for first in ordered_dict.items():
    break  # Leave the name 'first' bound to the first item
else:
    raise IndexError("Empty ordered dict")
```

The Python 2.x code corresponding to the first example above would need to use iteritems() instead:

```
for item in ordered_dict.iteritems():
    return item
```

Comment: `next(iter(self.items()))` will give you the first pair `(key, val)`

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using `SortedDict` instead of `OrderedDict`.

It provides `SortedDict.peekitem` to peek an item.

Runtime complexity: O(log(n))

```
>>> sd = SortedDict({'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3})
>>> sd.peekitem(0)
('a', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need a one-liner:

```py
ordered_dict[[*ordered_dict.keys()][0]]
```

It creates a list of dict keys, picks the first and use it as key to access the dictionary value.

Answer (score -2):

**First record**:

```
[key for key, value in ordered_dict][0]
```

**Last record**:

```
[key for key, value in ordered_dict][-1]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution to StackOverflow! While this works and is straightforward to understand, this is a very inefficient way to do it, as the whole list will have to be created in memory, before the single element you want can be extracted.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @galaga4! Can you help me here - Looks like this is will create a List which is not needed!

Comment: The fact that it is inefficient does not make it wrong. It's a perfectly fine solution and may be an easy way to get what OP wants for short lists.

Comment: `next(iter(self.items()))` will give you the first pair `(key, val)`