# KeyError: 0 in Python

Tags: python, json, keyerror

I'm trying to get the values of the first object's `direction` and `station`  returned in this JSON, but I'm getting the following error

> KeyError: 0

Here's my code:

```
print(json.dumps(savedrequest, indent=4))
savedstation = savedrequest[0]['station']
saveddirection = savedrequest[0]['direction']
```

And this is what it's returning in the print:

```
{
     "-bas": {
         "email_address": "dd3@gmail.com", 
         "direction": "Southbound", 
         "station": "place-har"
     }, 
     "-bus": {
         "email_address": "dd4@gmail.com", 
         "direction": "Southbound", 
         "station": "place-su"
     }
 }
```

**I don't know what `-bas` or `-bus` is going to be when it gets returned, I need to select the first object in the array.**

Comment: `savedrequest` isn't an array, it doesn't have a key `0`.  You need to use `'-bas'` (or `'-bus'`).

Comment: In that array, is there a way of selecting the first object and getting the values from those `direction` and `station` keys?

Comment: Why are you accessing key `0`?

Comment: You dont have list, so you need to use key: e.g. -bus.

Comment: I don't know what `-bas` or `-bus` is going to be, I just need to select the first object in the array

Comment: you should to use ```['-bas']['station']```

Comment: There *is* no array. You have a JSON *object* that gets converted to a python *dict*. Dictionaries in python are inherently unordered, so there is no concept of a 'first' element

Comment: Where is this `savedrequest` object coming from?

Comment: It's not an array, it's a dictionary. Dictionaries are not ordered, so you can't access them using [0], [1], etc. You can only access them by keys in the dictionary. There's no other way.

Comment: If you just want to get an arbitrary value out of the array, you can do something like: `savedrequest.popitem()[0]` or `savedrequest.values()[0]`

Comment: @JoelCornett I'm consistently getting this JSON back in the same order from a third party API. Is there a way at getting the first one in the group?

Comment: @RocketHazmat third party API call.

Comment: @beaconhill Even pure JSON objects are not guaranteed to be ordered so I would avoid depending on object ordering if at all possible. (ref: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt, see section 1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your JSON was decoded into an "object" (called a `dict` in python), it's not an array.  As such, it has no particular "order".  What you think is the "first" element may not actually be stored that way.  There's no guarantee that the same object will be first each time.

What you could try, however, is to convert these `dict`s into `OrderedDict`s by using the `object_pairs_hook` parameter of `json.loads` (and `json.load`).  An `OrderedDict` is like a `dict`, but it remembers the that order elements were inserted into it.

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

savedrequest = json.loads(data, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)

# Then you can get the "first" value as `OrderedDict` remembers order
#firstKey = next(iter(savedrequest))
first = next(iter(savedrequest.values()))

savedstation = first['station']
saveddirection = first['direction']
```

<sub>(This answer is thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921760 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067850)</sub>