# Parse defined variable in python to text file

Tags: python

I am new and seeking help if someone can. I have been able to create a text file with the output of the defined variable weight. But it writes/prints/posts much more data than I am needing. The followin .py I have is below.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import myfitnesspal
import requests
import lxml
import measurement
import six
import mock
import datetime

client = myfitnesspal.Client('username', 'password')

weight = client.get_measurements('Weight')
print weight

file = open("ChrisFitPal.txt", "w") 
file.write(repr(weight) + '\n' )
file.close()
```

The output I get is the following in a text file But I only want it to show a snippet of the text

This is what it shows in a text file

OrderedDict([(datetime.date(2019, 1, 2), ***174.4***), (datetime.date(2018, 12, 26), 175.6), (datetime.date(2018, 12, 21), 175.1), (datetime.date(2018, 12, 13), 173.2), (datetime.date(2018, 12, 7), 175.0)])

I just want the text file to show the number that is in bold and italics and nothing else. So the output would be just

174.4

is this possible?

Comment: You mean you want the most recent measurement? So what have you tried?

Comment: Print weight displays exactly "OrderedDict([(datetime.date(2019, 1, 2), 174.4), (datetime.date(2018, 12, 26), 175.6), (datetime.date(2018, 12, 21), 175.1), (datetime.date(2018, 12, 13), 173.2), (datetime.date(2018, 12, 7), 175.0)])"

Answer (score 0):

You can change:

```
file.write(repr(weight) + '\n' )
```

To:

```
file.write(a[next(iter(a))] + '\n' )
```

Where:

```
a = OrderedDict([(datetime.date(2019, 1, 2), 174.4), (datetime.date(2018, 12, 26), 175.6), (datetime.date(2018, 12, 21), 175.1), (datetime.date(2018, 12, 13), 173.2), (datetime.date(2018, 12, 7), 175.0)])
```

This gives you an iterator object of the `OrderedDict` values. You call `next` to advance the iterator by 1, giving you the key of the first item. You then use that key to access the value stored against that. There are a few options given by Raymond Hettinger [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067850/4799172)

Comment: It isn't a single value, is it?  It's a series of date-weight (presumably in pounds) values.

Comment: @JohnGordon the "bold, italics" literally is a single value so I've taken it literally. They seem to be pretty clear on a single output?

Comment: @JohnGordon oops, ok, we were coming from different angles. I didn't intend to imply the `OrderedDict` only contained one value, only that I was unsure why you'd have such a structure and only want the first value. Removed that statement.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are returning a dict from `client.get_measurements('Weight')`, so you can cast it to a list and index in to get only a certain item

```
d={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

list(d.items())
[('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]

list(d.items())[0]
('a', 1)

list(d.items())[0][1]
1
```